# NavigationView, multiple menus

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to use the NavigationView in one of my projects to implement a side menu. The app has two type of users: Admin and User.

I created the login activity and I log in as user or admin. I pass the name, email via intent (putExtra) to my NavigationActivity.

Since I have two type of users I created two type of menus (admin has more menu options).

I check the content of the passed value from the intent and inflate the navigation views menu accordingly.

My problem is I don't know how to separate in the listener the two type of menus. Should I create in my if else two listeners for each case? What would be the right approach? The way I did it doesn't work correctly, in my side menu I have the first two items from the user menu and after that the reamining items of the admin menu.

Here's thecode:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String name = extras.getString("name");
        String email = extras.getString("email");
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        if(name.equals("admin")){
        // listener for admin here?
            navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.admin_drawer);
        }else{
        // listener for user here?
            navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.user_drawer);
        }
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            // questionable part here, doesn't work correctly 
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                if(item.isChecked())
                    item.setChecked(false);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    // this is for user
                    case R.id.test:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        TestFragment testFragment = new TestFragment();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameholder, testFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        return true;
                    // this is for user
                    case R.id.practice:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Practice Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    // this is for admin  
                    case R.id.existing_questions:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Questions Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    // this is for admin
                    case R.id.new_questions:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"New questions Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    // this is for admin 
                    case R.id.settings:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Settings Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    // this is for admin
                    case R.id.users_data:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User data Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Edit:

Here you have the two menus I use:
admin_drawer.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/existing_questions"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_existq"
            android:title="Questions" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/new_questions"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_addq"
            android:title="Add question" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
            android:title="Settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/users_data"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_statistics"
            android:title="Statistics" />


    </group>
</menu>
```

user_drawer.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_test"
            android:title="Test" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/practice"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_practice"
            android:title="Practice" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: Your problem doesn't relate to the listeners, probably you have inflated the navigation view two times, with different menu layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks cylon. The mistake was made by me. I inflated the navigation view in the xml, and then from code to.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach would be to use two groups with different IDs in the same menu. Then you can switch between them easly with **.setGroupVisible()** like this:

```
if(name.equals("admin")){    
  navigationView.menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.menu_group_admin, true);
  navigationView.menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.menu_group_user, false);
}
else{
  navigationView.menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.menu_group_admin, false);
  navigationView.menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.menu_group_user, true);
}
```

This works seamlessly